# Uno Platform - Reference resource dictionary within Shared project

Tags: xaml, uno-platform, shared-project

I'm building an Uno app and need to reference a Resource Dictionary defined and stored in the Shared Project.

The project is set up like so:

[image: Project structure]

And in `MainPage.xaml`, I'm using:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///LaunchShowcase.Shared/Themes/CenteredPivotHeadersStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

This results in the error message `Cannot locate resource from 'ms-appx:///LaunchShowcase.Shared/Themes/CenteredPivotHeadersStyle.xaml'`

What's the proper way to reference this resource dictionary?

Comment: Just to check - this doesn't work in UWP either right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared project is not a "real" project, as would a library. The resource dictionary file is behaving as if it were directly integrated in the head project, therefore the name `LaunchShowcase.Shared` does not exist.

Try using this instead:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Themes/CenteredPivotHeadersStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```